# APL programming - assigning values to vectors

Tags: for-loop, vector, apl

Recently, I've been trying to get into APL. However, one problem I've had a frequent problem with is assigning values to vectors.

For certain programs where I intend to get multiple results (for example, a program that turns a character or a string of letters into 8-bit binary vectors), I have tried making a makeshift for loop, and then assigning the i-th part of my range vector with the correct value. For example, with the char->bin vector program:

```
r = 8[rho]' ' (creates a vector of length 8 with only blank spaces)
i = 8
e = [the numerical value of character c]
a1: r[8-i] <- 1
r[8-i] <- 0(if)(0=2|e)
e <- (floor value of e/2)
i = i - 1
->a1(if)i != 1
```

However, every time I've tried this, I've gotten a length error at the line where r[x] is assigned a value. What's wrong with my program, and how do I fix it?

Comment: From the two questions you have asked on this site about APL, it is clear that whatever you are doing, taking a class as a student or self-study, your approach is not working. You need an introductory course in APL.  Find a copy of Ray Polivka's "APL2 at a Glance", or any APL introductory text, read it and go through the exercises. You are just wasting your time otherwise.

Comment: I would recommend studying on a good textbook too. I found APL—An Interactive Approach by Gilman & Rose (a veritable classic) to be one of the best books ever written on how to approach programming in APL, even if it doesn't cover modern features such as D-funs. It's easily found on eBay or in second-hand bookshops. http://books.google.it/books?id=1ddWAAAAMAAJ

Comment: Gilman and Rose, though an early version, is available here: http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/apl/Books/GillmanAndRose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that was needed to get your original example to work, apart from a bit of clean up, was to simplify the "if" statement.

```
     ∇ r←foo1 c;i;e;⎕IO
[1]    ⎕IO←0
[2]    r←8⍴0 ⍝ creates a vector of length 8 with only blank spaces
[3]    i←8
[4]    e←⎕AV⍳c ⍝ arbitrary choice of numeric value of a char
[5]   a1:r[8-i]←2|e ⍝ simplified this here, no "if" needed
[6]    e←⌊e÷2
[7]    i←i-1
[8]    →(i≠1)/a1
     ∇
```

The problem was that apparently the arguments of the indexed assignment did not match.  Given r[x]←y, x and y must match in rank and shape (or length if vectors).  An important exception is **scalar extension**, where y can be scalar.  Best to experiment.

Be that as it may, a more APL-esque way to do this very problem is to use the **encode** ( ⊤ ) function, which does the division loop for you.  That solution would be simply

```
     ∇ r←foo2 c;⎕IO
[1]    ⎕IO←0
[2]    r←⌽(8⍴2)⊤⎕av⍳c
     ∇
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Which implementation of APL are you using? Most APL-Venoders (that I know) now support Unicode either Copy&Paste directly in Unicode or offer ways to turn APL into unicode...which you could then paste here, instead of transcribing it...
2. You said that you are still getting into APL. On of the key aspects of APL is the "array-thinking". With AT, you wouldn't need to loop over elements of a vector, but would work with vectors straight away.
3. Another aspect where you might be able to improve are control-structures. Most APLs these days offer some flavour of cs - which is why I asked 1.
4. The problem with your assignment is the `if`-function which you didn't show. But typically an `if`-function would return its right argument if the condition was true, and otherwise an empty vector. So, in your case, when the condition is not met, you are trying to insert an empty vector into position of an array - but only scalars would be accepteable there (unless you used nested arrays, which would be total overkill for this problem).

So,here is a version which is rather close to yours, but uses control-structures and converts a given numeric value to binary:

```
 r←foo c;i;⎕IO;res
 ⍝ Converts integer value c to binary (loopy-version)
 ⎕IO←0
 i←7
 r←8⍴0
 :if (i>255)∨(i≠⌊i)∨i<0 ⋄ r←¯1 ⋄ :endif  ⍝ some cases we do not want to handle and return ¯1 to indicate error
 :While i≥0
     res←1=⌊c÷2*i
     r[7-i]←res
     c←c-res×2*i
     i-←1
 :EndWhile
```

However, this solution is only provided to illustrate some ways of implementing some of the general aspects in APL (and to give you some things to look into when learning APL). For the given problem, the "real" APL-Solution would be `(8⍴2)⊤number`

Finally, if you want to not only "get into" APL, but are interested in mastering APL, there is a book available with that exact title ;-) (free download!) from http://dyalog.com/mastering-dyalog-apl.htm where you will also find other helpful links and a free student-version...

Comment: @user17103: if I answered your question, it would be cool if you could check my reply as solution. That is considered good practice here and will help to get replies for further questions. If it did not answer your q, pls. let me know what's missing ;-)